# JSON response from API request seems to be invalid in Python requests, but OK in Browser

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to read the response from an API, but whenever I try to access the JSON elements _ keep getting errors like:

```
...
...
    print(parsed_data['result']['listing']['whisper'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

My current code looks like:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   

item_data_api = "https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/fetch/e6c3075c2bea510e868dd9568930c74cfd7d926e2dc74dd12b1119ecb565b3ff"
r = requests.get(item_data_api)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.encoding)
    parsed_data = r.json()
    print(parsed_data)
    print(parsed_data['result']['listing']['whisper'])
```

If I get the output from print and validate the JSON on https://jsonlint.com/, it is not valid:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{  'id': 'e6c3075c2bea5
---^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

However, if I execute the call in a browser, the response is valid.

What am I missing here? Can someone please provide a hint on how to make the output valid? I already tried `json.loads(r.text)` but doesn't work either.

Comment: `parsed_data` is *Python*, not JSON; it's already been parsed. If the JSON was wrong, `r.json()` would have failed. But as you can see, `parsed_data = [...]` - the root element is a *list*, not a dictionary. You need to access the elements *based on what types they actually are*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the issues is the data you are being returned is not in the format you are expecting.

This line:

```
print(parsed_data['result']['listing']['whisper'])
```

assumes that you are getting a dictionary that looks like:

```
result = {
    "results": { 
        "listing": {
            "whisper": ...}}}
```

That's not what is being returned, it's more like:

```
result = {
    "results": [
        {"listing": ... }
        {"listing": ... }]}
```

So results is actually returning a list of dictionaries, which is why you get the error - you can't index into a list using a string.

If I run your code, and pull out the first results dictionary I don't get your error:

```
print(parsed_data['result'][0]['listing']['whisper'])
```